# Make a torrent client use a different internet connection

Tags: networking, internet, bittorrent

I have a wired Internet connection and I have dongles from which I can browse the internet.

Is there any way I can make the torrent client use the wired connection (since its unlimited) and browse the internet using my dongle, on the same computer.

Basically two internet connections on the same PC, just used for different purposes.

Is that possible in Windows 8.1, is that possible at all ? I am using Vuze as the bit torrent client.

Comment: Wired connection is unlimited means why you need another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `Advanced Network Settings` paragraph on [this](https://wiki.vuze.com/w/UG_Options#Connection_options) page. Vuze gives you the option to bind it to a local IP address or interface.

> Bind to local IP: This option allows you to bind Azureus to a specfic
>   IP address and thus a (virtual) network device. This may be useful if
>   you have multiple internet connections.

Comment: Well I had to use ForceBindIP anyway to modify Chrome to use my dongle. But yes you were right about Vuze. The followed the following [tutorial](http://geekyadmins.com/how-to-use-forcebindip-on-windows-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Install a proxy server on the machine, and bind it to a specific connection (by IP and Gateway).

Leave bittorrent client to do its thing on its own, and point your browser at the proxy server.